# Getting Null output while scraping website

Tags: python, scrapy, splash-screen, scrapy-splash

I am writing a web scraping program for this website, http://www.starcitygames.com/catalog/category/Duel%20Decks%20Venser%20vs%20Koth, and in the data table on the website there are instances where one card name has two different conditions/prices/stock... and I need both lines of information but as you will notice in the attached picture that the card name is only in the top row not the bottom. So for example with Aether Membrane it will output the card name plus all the other info but on the next line I get all the other information but for the card name I get Null.  Is there a way to like set up an if statement or something to where it sees if the card name is null and if so set card name equal to previous entry.  I need something to replace the Null characters with the correct card names.

SplashSpider.py

```
import csv
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from ..items import GameItem

# process the csv file so the url + ip address + useragent pairs are the same as defined in the file # returns a list of dictionaries, example:
# [ {'url': 'http://www.starcitygames.com/catalog/category/Rivals%20of%20Ixalan',
#    'ip': 'http://204.152.114.244:8050',
#    'ua': "Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry 9320; en-GB) AppleWebKit/534.11"},
#    ...
# ]
def process_csv(csv_file):
    data = []
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(reader)
    for fields in reader:
        if fields[0] != "":
            url = fields[0]
        else:
            continue # skip the whole row if the url column is empty
        if fields[1] != "":
            ip = "http://" + fields[1] + ":8050" # adding http and port because this is the needed scheme
        if fields[2] != "":
            useragent = fields[2]
        data.append({"url": url, "ip": ip, "ua": useragent})
    return data


class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'splash_spider'  # Name of Spider

    # notice that we don't need to define start_urls
    # just make sure to get all the urls you want to scrape inside start_requests function

    # getting all the url + ip address + useragent pairs then request them
    def start_requests(self):

        # get the file path of the csv file that contains the pairs from the settings.py
        with open(self.settings["PROXY_CSV_FILE"], mode="r") as csv_file:
           # requests is a list of dictionaries like this -> {url: str, ua: str, ip: str}
            requests = process_csv(csv_file)

        for req in requests:
            # no need to create custom middlewares
            # just pass useragent using the headers param, and pass proxy using the meta param

            yield SplashRequest(url=req["url"], callback=self.parse, args={"wait": 3},
                    headers={"User-Agent": req["ua"]},
                    splash_url = req["ip"],
                    )
    # Scraping
    def parse(self, response):
        item = GameItem()
        for game in response.css("tr[class^=deckdbbody]"):
            # Card Name
            item["card_name"] = game.css("a.card_popup::text").extract_first()
            item["condition"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_7 a::text").get()

            item["stock"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_8::text").extract_first()
            item["price"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_9::text").extract_first()

            yield item
```

Sample Output

```
{"card_name": "\nAether Membrane", "Condition": "NM/M", "stock": "93", "Price": "$0.59"},
{"card_name": null, "Condition": "PL", "stock": "59", "Price": "$0.49"},
{"card_name": "\nAngelic Shield", "Condition": "NM/M", "stock": "35", "Price": "$0.25"},
{"card_name": "\nAnger", "Condition": "NM/M", "stock": "9", "Price": "$1.49"},
{"card_name": null, "Condition": "PL", "stock": "49", "Price": "$1.19"},
{"card_name": "\nArmillary Sphere", "Condition": "NM/M", "stock": "87", "Price": "$0.25"},
{"card_name": "\nAugury Owl", "Condition": "NM/M", "stock": "Out of Stock", "Price": "$0.29"},
```

[image: Screenshot of Website]

Comment: create a saved variable (say: saved_name) and assign the value of name if not blank. Then on the next iteration of your loop, use this saved_name if name is blank.

Comment: Example is not verifiable as you have not included GameItem.py, however  âńōŋŷXmoůŜ above is correct.

Comment: Ok thank you very helpful and it worked perfectly.  It was very simple too I just could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like the comments said this fixed the problem:

```
 for game in response.css("tr[class^=deckdbbody]"):
            saved_name  = game.css("a.card_popup::text").extract_first() or saved_name
            item["card_name"] = saved_name.strip()

            if item["card_name"] != None:
                saved_name = item["card_name"].strip()
            else:
                item["card_name"] = saved_name

            item["Condition"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_7 a::text").get()
            item["stock"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_8::text").extract_first()
            item["Price"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_9::text").extract_first()

            yield item
```